# How to use SVProgressHUD in both ios app and its extension

Tags: ios, xcode, podfile, svprogresshud

I have a project of an iOS app and its share extension using libraries like Alamofire and FileKit. Everything was working perfectly with the following `Podfile`:

```
target 'myApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'BRYXBanner'
end
target 'myAppShareExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'FileKit', '~> 4.0.1'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```

Then, I wanted to use `SVProgressHUD`. First, I just added it to the main app and everything was okay. The problems began when I wanted to use it also in the extension. Since then, I changed the Podfile several times and none allowed me to have it in both the app and the extension. Worse, I cannot even use it again in the main app. As soon as I add it to the `Podfile`, my app fails to compile. Even `Alamofire` and `FileKit` cannot compile anymore.

Here is my new Podfile, the only one that does not generate any error during `pod install`.

```
platform :ios, '10.2'
use_frameworks!
target 'myApp' do
       target 'myAppShareExtension' do
                pod 'SVProgressHUD', :git => 'https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.git'
                pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
                pod 'FileKit', '~> 4.0.1'
       end
end
```

When I try to compile, I have the following errors, even without trying to import SVProgressHUD nor using it:

```
'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.
```

Note that when I use this latter Podfile, my extension target is named `Pods-myApp-myAppShareExtension` while it should be `Pods-myAppShareExtension` which makes me think the problem comes from the podfile

If you have any suggestion about the Podfile syntax, the build environment etc, please do not hesitate. I can provide additional information about

Edit: Note that I tried different build settings options and maybe I messed up with something there.

Answer (score 2):

After you see where the error is, you will understand what the problem is.

```
#if !defined(SV_APP_EXTENSIONS)
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation;
#else
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) > CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) ? UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft : UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
#endif
```

Do you see the `SV_APP_EXTENSIONS`? That means if the target is not an App Extensions, it will compile the above code, if it is, it will compile the under code. So for now, you need it to work in your App Extension target, you need to add the preprocessor macro to your App Extension target.

[image]